# Issue with redirection in IIS 10

Tags: iis

I have hosted a website in IIS but the site is always redirecting to Https localhosts eventhough i provided only http protocol port.

[image]

but when i browse the site it is redirecting to
https://localhost/

No idea why this site is behaving like this ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be an HTTP redirect rule, click on your site, and then find the URL rewrite component, delete the rules you don’t need, so that no redirection will occur.

[image]

Comment: No there is no rule mentioned in the component.

Comment: Check whether SSL settings are selected to require SSL.